# Sending mail with Phpmailer, BCC only, hiding TO header field

Tags: php, email, header, phpmailer, bcc

I'm using **Phpmailer** to send an email to **multiple accounts** using BCC.

I don't want "**To:**" field to be seen among the headers, but I think it is mandatory, because if I omit it I got this error:

```
Email error: You must provide at least one recipient email address
```

As a workaround I use my sender email under

```
$mail->addAddress (sendermail@domain.com);
```

but I'd like to send only BCC recipes.

Is it possible to do so or must I loop through all the emails recipe and send them one at a time?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use undisclosed-recipients:;

```
$mail->AddAddress("undisclosed-recipients:;");
$mail->AddBCC(bcc@email.com); //there may be foreach loop
```

Comment: Thank you, hadn't thought 'bout it! Solved.

Comment: This is just wrong. That call to `addAddress` does nothing because `undisclosed-recipients:;` is not a valid address, and if you check you'll see it returns `false`. Calling `addBCC` is the right way to go, but this example is syntactically invalid and won't even compile.

Comment: Ok, in fact undisclosed-recipients:; generates error. But I simply can't omit AddAddress because it  returns this error: `Email error: You must provide at least one recipient email address`

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer deals with this for you automatically. Just don't add any `to` addresses (i.e. don't call `addAddress()`), and add some BCC addresses:

```
$mail->addBCC('user@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('user2@example.net');
```

PHPMailer will automatically set the `to` header to the empty `undisclosed-recipients:;` group.

Comment: Sorry but if I don't use addAddress() i get this error: Email error: You must provide at least one recipient email address

Comment: Look at [how this check works](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L1367). Are you checking whether your calls to `addBCC` are successful?

Comment: Yes they are, indeed... but you are right. Don't know what to think.

Comment: You're doing something wrong - I just tested this and it works as described. It would help if you posted all your code in the question.